# how to set the number of lines that will be filtered with {dplyr} in a function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

In an R function, how to set the number of lines that will be filtered with {dplyr} ?

Here's my example.
Many thanks in advance !

```
library(dplyr)

myfunction <- function(base,
                       start_row=1,
                       end_row=Inf) {

  base %>% slice(start_row:end_row)  
}

result <- myfunction(base=iris,
                     start_row = 1,
                     end_row = 50)
# => works

result <- myfunction()
# Error in start_row:end_row : result would be too long a vector
```

Comment: do `end_row = nrow(iris)` as default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `nrow(base)` as default:

```r
myfunction <- function(base,
                       start_row = 1,
                       end_row = nrow(base)) {
  
  base %>% 
    slice(start_row:end_row)  
}
```

output

```r
dim(myfunction(iris))
#[1] 150   5
```